# Encode multiple BitmapSources for printing - Cache problems

Tags: c#, wpf, caching, printing

I need to print a lot of big sized images in a WPF application (using `PrintDialog.PrintDocument()`). To reduce traffic (or pdf file size if user prints to pdf file) I want to encode the images into jpg.

I have my images as a collection of `BitmapSources` and a method that looks similar to this:

```
privat PageContent CreatePageForImage(BitmapSource bitmapSource)
{
    // encode the image
    var encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder { QualityLevel = 100 };
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource));

    // get the encoded image
    JpegBitmapDecoder decoder;
    using (var encoderStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        encoder.Save(encoderStream);

        using (var decoderStream = new MemoryStream(encoderStream.ToArray(), false))
        {
            decoder = new JpegBitmapDecoder(decoderStream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.None);
        }
    }

    var image = new Image();
    image.Source = decoder.Frames[0];

    // ...
    // a page is created, image added and page returned
    // ...
}
```

Problem: for all my `image` controls it seems that I get the same image as source. Seems to be a caching problem. The bitmapSources are definitely different.

Questions: How can I fix this / disable the cache? Is the encode stream beeing cached, too? Is there a better way of achieving what I want?

Comment: My pdf print file was about 20 MB of size (4 pages) before adding the jpeg encoder and decoder. Now it is about 300 KB, but has the same image on each page.

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602494.aspx) says `Use the OnLoad cache option if you wish to close the bitmapStream after the decoder is created`. So you should write `new JpegBitmapDecoder(decoderStream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad)`. Don't know if that helps however.

Comment: Thanks for your research, but it does not help. :-(